# Descargar automáticamente archivo CSV con PHP y PDO

Tags: php, pdo, csv, php7

Tengo el siguiente código `PHP` para crear un archivo `CSV` con información de la base de datos `MySQL` y lo guarda en el directorio donde esté el archivo que contiene el código `exportar.php`.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$salida = fopen('saldos.csv', 'w');

if ($salida) {
    # Los encabezados no son requeridos en este caso
    # fputs($salida, "Documento, Obtenido, Acumulado, Nuevo".PHP_EOL);

    $sql = "SELECT documento, obtenido, acumulado, nuevo FROM datos WHERE semana = 3 ";
    $stmt = $dbcon->query($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            fputs($salida, implode($fila, ';').PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    fclose($salida);
} else {
    echo "Lo sentimos! No se pudo crear el archivo";
}
?>
```

¿Qué debo agregar para que no guarde el archivo sino que lo descargue automáticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descargar automáticamente el archivo `.csv` , será necesario modificar los [encabezados](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) de la siguiente manera.

[Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) Para indicar el tipo de archivo o recurso.

[Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) , `attachment` (indicando que será descargado; seguido del nombre del archivo `filename`)

[readfile()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php) para la salida del archivo `csv.`

```
//necesario si tiene más contenido en su archivo PHP. 
//puede que se añada contenido HTML innecesario.
ob_end_clean(); 
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=saldos.csv');
readfile("./saldos.csv");
```